# 1 dimension indexes or multiple index

Tags: mongodb

I have a query where the criteria is as follow (PHP):

```
 ...
 ->findBy(['userId'=>new \MongoId($me),'active'=>1],array('date' => 'DESC'),10);
```

I'm wondering whether it would be more efficient to use a triple index than using a simple index on userId for example.

My other question is : the field `active` can change; does it still make sense to create an index on this field ? if yes , how do indexes update their values ?

Comment: We know way too little to answer factually, we don't know your data distribution, formation, etc etc etc, I would do as saj says and check whether it is slow and investigate/test which patterns of indexes are faster. Also remember that index intersectioning is only in 2.6+ so make sure you have that version before you go making multiple indexes for a query

Comment: As for how MongoDB updates its index values, it does it atomically on updating/inserting the document

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mongodb profiler,  to find which of your queries are slow & then index the fields that have a 'where' clause, example

```
 db.system.profile.find( { millis : { $gt : 5 } } ).pretty()
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Comment: You can also go the simpler route of using explain()